# Running multiple instances of a CrawlSpider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i'm just getting started using scrapy and i'd like to do the following

```
Have a list of n domains
i=0
loop for i to n
Use a (mostly) generic CrawlSpider to get all links (a href) of domain[i]
Save results as json lines
```

to do this, the Spider needs to receive the domain it has to crawl as an argument.

I already successfully created the CrawlSpider:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MyItem(Item):
    #MyItem Fields


class SubsiteSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "subsites"
    start_urls = []
    allowed_domains = []
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)

    def __init__(self, starturl, allowed, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        self.start_urls.append(starturl)
        self.allowed_domains.append(allowed)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def parse_obj(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        #fill Item Fields
        return item


process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'})
process.crawl(SubsiteSpider)
process.start()
```

If i call it with `scrapy crawl subsites -a starturl=http://example.com -a allowed=example.com -o output.jl`
the result is exactly as i want it, so this part is fine already.

What i fail to do is create multiple instances of `SubsiteSpider`, each with a different domain as argument.

I tried (in SpiderRunner.py)

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl('subsites', ['https://example.com', 'example.com'])
process.start()
```

Variant:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

allowed = ["example.com"]
start = ["https://example.com"]
process.crawl('subsites', start, allowed)
process.start()
```

But i get an error that occurs, i presume, because the argument is not properly passed to `__init__`, for example `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'allowed'` or `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'starturl' and 'allowed'`
(Loop is yet to be implemented)

So, here are my questions:
1) What is the proper way to pass arguments to **init**, if i do not start crawling via scrapy shell, but from within python code?
2) How can i also pass the -o output.jl argument? (or maybe, use allowed argument as filename?)
3) I am fine with this running each spider after another - would it still be considered best / good practice to do it that way? Could you point to a more extensive tutorial about "running the same spider again and again, with different arguments(=target domains), optionally parallel", if there is one?

Thank you all very much in advance!
If there are any spelling mistakes (not an english native speaker), or if question / details are not precise enough, please tell me how to correct them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. `start_urls` and `allowed_domains` are class attributes which you modify in `__init__()`, making them shared across all instances of your class.
   What you should do instead is make them instance attributes:

   ```
   class SubsiteSpider(CrawlSpider):
       name = "subsites"
       rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)

       def __init__(self, starturl, allowed, *args, **kwargs):
           self.start_urls = [starturl]
           self.allowed_domains = [allowed]
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
2. Those last 3 lines should not be in the file with you spider class, since you probably don't want to run that code each time your spider is imported.
3. Your calling of [`CrawlProcess.crawl()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.crawl) is slightly wrong. You can use it like this, passing the arguments in the same manner you'd pass them to the spider class' `__init__()`.

   ```
   process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
   process.crawl('subsites', 'https://example.com', 'example.com')
   process.start()
   ```

> How can i also pass the -o output.jl argument? (or maybe, use allowed argument as filename?

You can achieve the same effect using [`custom_settings`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider), giving each instance a different `FEED_URI` setting.

Comment: Tank you very much, stranac. All 3 suggestions are correct and improved my code / solved the problem.

Comment: Your all suggestion are also worked for me, but I'm not getting a way to use list of sites to crawl, can you please explain little bit more about it. Thanks

Comment: The last snippet in the answer shows how to do it for a single website. For a list of them, just do the same in a for loop.